# How to Select Data From Multiple Tables using inner join statment?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have three tables

Products Table :

`ID
     GeneralStockEnabled
     RetailerID`

Sources Table

`ID
     Name
     RetailerID`

and

ProductInventory Table

`ProductID
     SourceID
     Stock`

The user will pass both the @RetailerID and @ProductID in my Stored Procedure.

How Can I select All the sources for particular retailer and attach the stock value coming from the product inventory table to those sources exists in the product inventory table for a particular product id and also select the value of GeneralStockEnabled for that product? . Even I my product has no stocks, I still want to be able to retrieve all the sources for that retailer?.

Any Help is appreciated.

I have this SQL right now :

```
SELECT S.ID AS SourceID,S.Name AS SourceName,PIN.Stock
FROM Sources S
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductInventory PIN
     ON (S.ID = PIN.SourceID)
WHERE S.RetailerID = 1
AND PIN.ProductID = 1
```

but since my product inventory table has no records now. It is not selecting the left part which are the sources in this case.

Comment: Read up on `JOIN`, in particular `LEFT JOIN` which allows you to get rows even when related rows do not exist in the other table. Post some SQL and then we can help with any specific problems.

Comment: You can join the three tables right? Product Table ID -> ProductInventory Table ID and Product Table RetailerID -> Sources Table RetailerID..

Comment: @iZ88 using inner join or left join ?

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
select s.*, pr.Stock, p.GeneralStockEnabled
    from sources s join
        Products p on s.RetailerId = p.RetailerId left outer join
        ProductInventory pr on pr.ProductId = p.Id
    where s.RetailerId = @RetailerId and p.id = @ProductId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins for the same

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp